# Failed to open file: Permission denied?

Tags: file, elasticsearch, file-permissions, logstash, kibana

I am running `logstash-1.4.1` on Ubuntu and get the following error:

```
failed to open /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-02/abc.log: Permission denied - /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-02/abc.log {:level=>:warn, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"107"}
```

Background: 
I copied the directory structure of logs from a remote server to my local machine. Now, on running logstash on my local machine on the directory structure I copied, this error occurs.

When I check permissions on the file, it's showing both read write.

Any idea?

As I now checked the logstash console, it's evident that logstash is **opening** some files and after that permission denied starts coming **till end**.

CONSOLE:

```
_open_file: /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-11/abc.log: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"98"}
/home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-11/abc.log: initial create, no sincedb, **seeking to beginning** of file {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"133"}
_open_file: /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-21/abc.log: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"98"}
/home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-21/abc.log: initial create, no sincedb, **seeking to beginning** of file {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"133"}
_open_file: /home/Desktop/Input/2014-11-04/abc.log: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"98"}
failed to open /home/Desktop/Input/2014-11-04/abc.log: **Permission denied** - /home/Desktop/Input/2014-11-04/abc.log {:level=>:warn, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"107"}
_open_file: /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10/abc.log: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"98"}
failed to open /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10/abc.log: **Permission denied** - /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10/abc.log {:level=>:warn, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"107"}
```

Is it because of some limit might be there to **number of files** opened, as logstash is opening files till a limit and after that gives permission denied errors??

My file permissions for files it gives permission denied error:

```
ls -l ./Input/2014-11-04/abc.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userA userA 0 Nov 12 09:56 ./Input/2014-11-04/abc.log

 ls -ld ./Input/2014-11-04
drwxrwxr-x 3 userA userA 4096 Nov 12 09:56 ./Input/2014-11-04

ls -l /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10/abc.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userA userA 0 Nov 12 09:56 /home/userA/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10/abc.log

ls -ld /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10
drwxrwxr-x 2 userA userA 4096 Nov 12 09:56 /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-10
```

**EDIT:**

Logstash is run using `userA`.

Detailed File Permissions:

```
ls -ld /home/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 27  2013 /home/

ls -ld /home/Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x 7 userA userA 4096 Nov 12 12:45 /home/Desktop/

 ls -ld /home/Desktop/Input/
drwxrwxr-x 47 userA userA 4096 Nov 12 10:50 /home/Desktop/Input/

ls -l /home/Desktop/Input/abc.log 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userA userA 0 Nov 12 09:56 /home/Desktop/Input/abc.log
```

Comment: As what user are you running logstash?  What permissions does that user have on the log file and all the directories leading to it?

Comment: @AlainCollins: It's not the root user. The permissions I have set temporarily are `-rwxrwxrwx 1 userA userA    0 Nov 11 14:12 abc.log*`

Comment: @AlainCollins: I have edited the question. Please check edits.

Comment: Don't just flail around and set file permissions to 777 (they need to be executable??).  You didn't say what user is running logstash, nor did you show the permissions of *all* the directories down to the files (/home, /home/Desktop, /home/Desktop/Input).

Comment: @AlainCollins: I have provided the details asked in the edit. Also, it's strange that logstash starts giving errors after certain files threshold is crossed. I tried after reducing files, it works fine that way.

Comment: Maybe you're having a ulimit open files problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logstash too many files opened?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907388/logstash-too-many-files-opened)