# Logstash too many files opened?

Tags: linux, file, elasticsearch, logstash

I am running `logstash 1.4.1` and on running it I am getting following on the console:

```
    failed to open /home/Desktop/Input/2014-11-03/abc.log: Permission denied - /home/Desktop/Input/2014-11-03/abc.log {:level=>:warn}
    failed to open /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-14/abc.log: Permission denied - /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-14/abc.log {:level=>:warn}
    failed to open /home/Desktop/2014-10-16/abc.log: Permission denied - /home/Desktop/Input/2014-10-16/abc.log {:level=>:warn}

..............

    log4j, [2014-11-13T16:20:04.583]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen: [logstash-HP-Pro-3330-MT-7573-11818] failed to connect to master [[Kyle Gibney][eM0ZmUkAQpaXd6_n4JWjzA][-HP-Pro-3330-MT][inet[/xx.xx..xx..xx:9300]]], retrying...
    org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Kyle Gibney][inet[/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300]] General node connection failure
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:668)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:615)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:338)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$500(ZenDiscovery.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:286)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.newSocket(NioClientSocketChannel.java:43)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.<init>(NioClientSocketChannel.java:82)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioClientSocketChannelFactory.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioClientSocketChannelFactory.java:82)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:702)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:647)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:423)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:416)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:104)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:142)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.newSocket(NioClientSocketChannel.java:41)
        ... 15 more
```

So logstash is opening files upto a certain threshold and after that giving permission denied for the files after that threshold and saying too many files opened.

Any idea?

Comment: Use root to `ulimit -l unlimited` and restart ES: http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/too-many-open-files/

Comment: Guess you didn't like the conversation in your original post?

Comment: @Allain: earlier was running logstash with -vv and the too many files error was not showing on the console, so this time I ran it with -v ( verbose) only and a new error of too many files showed up. Thus new question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check what's the limit of your file handle for your linux user. One place you could check is:

```
cat /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Where you define hard and soft limit. Another way would be to use ulimit command like below:

```
ulimit -a | grep nofiles ##Or ulimit -n
```

Comment: I do `ulimit -n` and it gives  `1024`

Comment: That means your process can open only 1024 files (be it connections or logstash file etc everything is a file)